# watermark and upload image on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, watermark

im trying to watermark my image on codeigniter
i can watermark image which i have to gave path and that works fine but i want to watermark  my image which im going to upload that means i choose files and watermark them and upload it to database so how can i do that here is my image uploading controller

Controller

```
function add_page() {

    $this->access_denied();
    //new page add from form process
    if($this->input->post('add')) {

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('slug', 'slug', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[200]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('details', 'details', 'trim|required');
      if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $slug = strip_tags(url_title($this->input->post('slug')));
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $details = $this->input->post('details');
        $publish_date = time();
        $added_by = $this->session->userdata('full_name');


        // if image is uploaded
        if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size']>0) {

          $config = array('upload_path' => './uploads/page/',
                          'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png|jpeg|ico',
                          'max_size' => 0,
                          'max_height' => 0,
                          'max_width' =>0
                        );
          $this->load->library('upload', $config);

          if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $image_files = $this->upload->data();z
            $this->page_model->add_page($slug, $title, $details, $image_files['file_name'], $publish_date, $added_by);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert") New page has been added successfully.</div>');
            redirect('page/manage-page');
          }
          else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', $this->upload->display_errors());
            redirect('page/add_page');
          }

        }
        else {
          $this->page_model->add_page($slug, $title, $details, null,$publish_date,$added_by);
          $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert") New page has been added successfully.</div>');
          redirect('page/manage-page');
        }
      }


    }
    $data = array('page_title' => "Add new page",
                  'keywords' =>"",
                  'description' => "",
                  'image' => "",
                  'url'=> "",
                  'author' => "",
                  'page_content' => $this->load->view('page/add', '', true)
                );
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
  }
```

i hope it wont freak you out guys but it would be great help for me thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html ??

Comment: Here is good example for watermarking in CI https://arjunphp.com/codeigniter-image-watermark/

Comment: thanks mitul bro so how can i set the source image dynamically ? i mean i want to upload image as well as watermarks it , @mitul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the good code which will help you for the image upload and watermarking

**Image Upload** and **Watermarking**

http://demo.codesamplez.com/codeigniter/image-demo

Answer (score 0):

You may use the library WideImage in PHP. It has the predefined functions for adding the watermarks. [link](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/merge-watermark/)

Comment: well im a newbies so i don't know what it is. is it work on codeigniter too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeigniter for Watermarking [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html)

```
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2006 - John Doe';
$config['wm_type'] = 'text';
$config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
$config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
$config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
$config['wm_padding'] = '20';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

$this->image_lib->watermark();
```